# C# Win Api DDE connection multithread

Tags: c#, multithreading, dde

I have function implementation of DDE client using Win Api in C#. Everything works fine in case that I call `DdeInitializeW` and `DdeConnect` in single thread.
Specifically, these are wrapper definitions:

```
    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    protected static extern int DdeInitializeW(ref int id, DDECallback cb, int afcmd, int ulres);

    [DllImport("user32.dll")]
    static extern IntPtr DdeConnect(
        int idInst,             // instance identifier
        IntPtr hszService,      // handle to service name string
        IntPtr hszTopic,        // handle to topic name string
        IntPtr pCC              // context data
        );
```

If I called `DdeInitializeW` and `DdeConnect` in different threads, `DdeConnect` return null pointer.

Also, if I called both of them (established DDE connection) in one thread, I can't use this DDE channel in another thread (i'm getting `INVALIDPARAMETER` DDE error).

As I said, everything works without problems in single thread.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The behaviour you describe is expected.

DDE is tied to the individual thread. This is because DDE (which is generally considered a legacy technology) works internally by passing windows messages, and windows handles (`HWND`) have thread affinity.

- You must call `DdeInitializeW` from the same thread you call `DdeConnect`.
- That thread must pump messages (so it cannot be a thread-pool thread).
- You will get callbacks/replies on that same thread also.

In other words you need to do your DDE from a thread which calls `Application.Run`, or which frequently calls `Application.DoEvents` at moments when it is appropriate for the events to be sent or received.

You can use DDE from more than one thread, but each must call `DdeInitializeW` and replies will always be received on the thread the request was sent from.

Comment: This is exactly how I'm doing it at this moment. OK I was afraid that this is issue of DDE itself. Thank you very much for ensuring me in it.

Comment: Also, tip if you aren't doing it already: Keep track of multiple DDE conversation by giving each conversation a unique id, using `DdeSetUserHandle` and `DdeQueryConvInfo`. This simplifies everything a lot. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms648765(v=vs.85).aspx